# How to return window.location.host on a static next.js site?

Tags: react-hooks, next.js

I would like to return {window.location.host} on a static next.js website

I managed to log the value but I can not figure out how to return it.

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Test() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(window.location.host);
  }, []);

  return <h1>{window.location.host}</h1>;
}
```

I'm a JS beginner, all I managed was to return it once on the initial page load with useEffect but after a reload it gives the error

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window is unavailable during server side rendering, you can a state hook and update it in your effect hook client side.

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export default function TestPage() {
  const [host, setHost] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") setHost(window.location.host);
  }, []);
  return <h1>{host}</h1>;
}
```

Comment: perfect! thanks a lot